# Python Shuffling Array Inadvertently

Tags: python, shuffle

I am trying to do a simple 1D-array shuffle in Python but keeping a copy of the original array. However, when calling shuffle commands (either np.random.shuffle or random.shuffle) Python will shuffle all of them in sync.

Example:

```
import numpy as np
arr = np.arange(10)
arr_backup = arr
print(arr)
print(arr_backup)
np.random.shuffle(arr)
print(arr)
print(arr_backup)
```

This prints:

```
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]
[1 4 9 5 8 6 3 2 7 0]
[1 4 9 5 8 6 3 2 7 0]
```

I guess I am not understanding how Python allocates this item in the namespace or something. Any help is appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: ```arr``` and ```arr_backup``` reference the same object in memory. just like with lists, dicts, etc, you have to explicitly copy the object to a new variable. What you've essentially done here is aliased the variable ```arr``` to ```arr_backup```. Modifying one will modify the other. You can test this by replacing ```np.random.shuffle(arr)``` with ```np.random.shuffle(arr_backup)```.

Comment: The assignment `arr_backup = arr` creates another name *for the same array*. When you then shuffle it, both names point to the same shuffled one. If you want a new copy of the array, try `arr_backup = arr.copy()`.

Comment: So why doesnt this change b to number 3 as well?
In [105]: a=2

In [106]: b=a


In [107]: a=3

In [108]: b
Out[108]: 2

Comment: @user191919 because **you never change the `int` object** (you can't anyway, because `int` objects are immutable. You simply assign a new object to the name `a`, namely `3`. The same thing works with `numpy.ndarray` objects, so `arr = np.arange(10); arr_backup = arr; arr = np.arange(20); print(arr_backup)`

Comment: @user191919 read the following: https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All variables in Python hold references to objects. Assignment from one variable to another just copies that reference, so both `arr` and `arr_backup` point to the same object in memory.

Shuffle mutates the array in-place, so the changes are reflected when you access the object from both references. To avoid that, you can copy the array by using `arr_backup = arr[:]` or `arr_backup = arr.copy()`

Comment: You don't want to call lost because that'll drop the array. You want `arr.copy()` here

Comment: You're absolutely right :)

Answer (score 0):

direct reference from the np docs.

> > > x = np.array([1, 2, 3])
> > >
> > > y = x
> > >
> > > z = np.copy(x)

Note that, when we modify x, y changes, but not z:

> > > x[0] = 10
> > >
> > > x[0] == y[0]
> > >       True
> > >
> > > x[0] == z[0]
> > >       False